# authorizeRequests() vs. authorizeHttpRequests​(Customizer<AuthorizeHttpRequestsConfigurer.AuthorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry>

Tags: spring, spring-security

I want to configure my spring application security, all of requests should be authenticated before being served.

So I created a filter chain bean:

```
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {
        return http
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().formLogin()
            .and().build();
    }
```

I also found out authorizeRequests method has an overload version which accepts an Customizer interface parameter.
So I tried the parameterized version.

```
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {
        return http
            .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests ->
                authorizeRequests.anyRequest().authenticated()
            )

            .formLogin()
            .and().build();
    }
```

I noticed parameterized authorizeRequests method would return the same HttpSecurity object so you can keep configuring without calling and().

Is that the only difference between them ? If that so, wouldn't this overloaded version seemed to be redundant ?

Answer (score 19):

Both ways of declaring `authorizeRequests` are valid. The one that accepts a customizer is a way to make your code easier to read because it avoids multiple indentation levels. Using the lambda customizer is recommended.

The difference between `authorizeRequests` and `authorizeHttpRequests` is explained [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/authorize-http-requests.html). The `authorizeHttpRequests` uses the new simplified `AuthorizationManager` API and the `AuthorizationFilter`, while `authorizeRequests` uses the `AccessDecisionManager` and `FilterSecurityInterceptor`. The latter will be deprecated in future version of Spring Security.

Comment: `authorizeRequests` is already deprecated in Spring Security 6.1.0