# Spring Security ignores URL patterns from requestMatchers

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I just created a new Spring Boot application with the following web security config (using spring-security-config:6.0.0):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {
   @Bean
   public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                    .requestMatchers("/", "/login", "/info/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
            )
            .formLogin((form) -> form
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .permitAll()
            )
            .logout(LogoutConfigurer::permitAll);

    return http.build();
   }
 }
```

When trying to access any url I get redirected to /login with ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS. Something seems to be wrong with my SecurityConfig.

In previous versions I always used `http.authorizeHttpRequests().antMatchers("/")` instead of requestMatchers but it seems like they removed it.

Does `requestMatchers()` do the same thing or how can I configure url patterns that don't require login?

Comment: Do you have `security.basic.enabled=false` in your `application.properites`?

Comment: @Youans no, I don't have any spring security properties set

Comment: Does it work if you append after   `authorizeHttpRequests`
`.and().httpBasic()`

Comment: My thinking is that you configured everything but you don't have `/login` endpoint, So when un-authenticated request reaches server spring security fall back to error page, which is also is not authenticated so it goes back to login and so on till you get the too many redirects error

Comment: which means also you should allow `/error` path

Comment: @Youans Unfortunately adding ``.and().httpBasic()`` didnt work. I want to use the default login form. The problem is that even urls that match the requestMatchers require login and I dont want that

Comment: I guess you are doing old way of authenticating which is deprecated see read this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73089730/authorizerequests-vs-authorizehttprequestscustomizerauthorizehttprequestsc

Comment: If you want to use the default login form you should not override `loginPage`, see the javadoc: **Specifies the URL to send users to if login is required. If used with EnableWebSecurity a default login page will be generated when this attribute is not specified.
If a URL is specified or this is not being used in conjunction with EnableWebSecurity, users are required to process the specified URL to generate a login page.**

Comment: I think @Youans is right, in order to debug try to permit the `/error` page

Comment: I did it exactly like in the docs for the corresponding spring security version, it isn't deprecated: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/authorize-http-requests.html

Comment: @Youans I analyzed further and my ``SecurityFilterChain`` seems ok, it looks like my controller redirects me to localhost:8080/info.jsp?continue instead of staying on localhost:8080/info. That explains why the pattern doesn't match