# Why is authorizeRequests() allowing access to endpoints that are not mentioned vs authorizeHttpRequests() which isn't?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security, authorization, deprecated

I have been trying to migrate an application to Springboot 3 and am facing an issue regarding the use of the deprecated `authorizeRequests()` vs. the recommended `authorizeHttpRequests(<Customizer>)` methods.
Previously my config was similar to this:

```
fun filterChain(http:Security): SecurityFilterChain {
    http.anonymous()
        .disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/somePath1/**").hasRole("A")
        .antMatchers("/somePath2/**").hasRole("B")
        .antMatchers("/somePath3/**").hasRole("C")
  return http.build()
}
```

This was working as intended, giving access to the paths to the respective roles. When I tried to access a different path `"/somePath5/**"`, it did not require any authorization/authentication. This is my intended behavior. All access is internal so disregard any security concerns here.

Now I am trying to replicate this behaviour using the recommended `authorizeHttpRequests(<Customizer>)`. I am trying the following code:

```
fun filterChain(http:Security): SecurityFilterChain {
    http.anonymous{ it.disable() }
        .authorizeHttpRequests {
            it.requestMatchers("/somePath1/**").hasRole("A")
              .requestMatchers("/somePath2/**").hasRole("B")
              .requestMatchers("/somePath3/**").hasRole("C")
              .anyRequest().permitAll()
        }
  return http.build()
```

I have had to add the final permission `.anyRequest().permitAll()` here. Without this, I am unable to access `"/somePath5/**"` like before and am getting 403 Forbidden.

What I would like to know is, why do I need the additional line when using `authorizeHttpRequests(<Customizer>)`? Is there something different between the 2 methods that I am missing?

The most I could google about this was in [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73090615). But I couldn't find any details when I followed the link, and if it's there, I can't understand it.

***Edit: I moved from Spring Security 5.7.3 to 6.1.0 during this migration***

Comment: Because that is a general rule in security. You want to close everything and open up only what you need/want. Instead of opening all the doors and close only those which are needed. Spring Security (or any other security framework for that matter) doesn't know if it is ok to disregard all security or not, hence you need to tell it what to do.

Comment: Totally understandable. I'm with you on that. I just want to know exactly what changed inside the implementation, such that all other paths are open when using `authorizeRequests`, but other paths are closed when using `authorizeHttpRequests`. Does Spring Security keep everything open by default and `authorizeRequests` doesn't close them, or does Spring Security keep everything closed by default and `authorizeHttpRequests` just opens the ones needed? I just noticed I moved from spring security 5.7.3 to 6.1.0. Just need help finding some reference docs to get details from.

Comment: Well the answer is basically in the question/answer you mention yourself, or rather in the documentation that is linked. A quote from the reference guide from Spring Security *By default, Spring Security requires that every request be authenticated* so that is the actual default, and has been for some time. Why you didn't need to add a `permitAll` in your previous config beats me, there was/is probably something that either disabled the defaults or overrides the default config already.